# Why does this program throws Segmentation fault exception?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a 2D array called `drevo`. I have located both dimensions of memory, so why does it throw this exception?

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int k;
    int stukaza;
    int parameter;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int **drevo = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(drevo + i) = (int *) malloc(10000 * sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d", *(drevo + i));

        for (int j = 1; j < (**(drevo + i)) + 1; i++) {

            printf("%d jlk", *(drevo));
            scanf("%d", *(drevo + 2));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving the program? And please use the syntax `drevo[i]` instead of `*(drevo+i)` as it's much more readable. `(**(drevo+i))` is concerning.

Comment: Please take notice of compiler warnings: 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of
 type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'

Comment: What is the purpose of your embedded for-loop?  It's not making use of either counting vars.  Also, `*(drevo)` is of type `int *` and you are printing it as if it is of type `int`.

Comment: [do i cast the return value of `malloc` in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. That means you can use `drevo[i]` in all places where you use `*(drevo + i)`.

While the above won't solve your problem, it might give you an idea what the problem is if you think of `drevo` as a pointer to an array of other pointer to arrays, similar to an array of arrays.

So in the loop when you use

```
*drevo + i) = (int *) malloc(10000 * sizeof(int));
scanf("%d", *(drevo + i));
```

it is equal to

```
drevo[i] = malloc(10000 * sizeof(int));
scanf("%d", drevo[i]);
```

That code will not be correct, as you will read into `drevo[i][0]` *always*.

However, that is still not the cause of the crash, it's just faulty logic.

The problem is probably this:

```
scanf("%d", *(drevo + 2));
```

It is equal to

```
scanf("%d", drevo[2]);
```

And that will read into `drevo[2][0]`. ***But*** in the very first iteration of the outer loop, when `i == 0`, then the pointer `drevo[2]` is *uninitialized!* It doesn't point anywhere valid, and by dereferencing that pointer you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and very likely the crash you are experiencing.

Try to convert all `*(drevo + i)` and similar expressions into `drevo[i]` and see if they all make sense. It is, by the way, a few less characters to write. Other than that, you should [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). We can not really help you more, since you don't tell us what your program is supposed to do, and with the flawed and faulty logic (and undefined behavior) it's hard for use to try and figure it out ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int j = 1; j < (**(drevo + i)) + 1; i++)
```

I think you want to increment j here not i, but it is a little bit unclear what you want to do.